# What's wrong with the definition?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to compile "libsamplerate.dll" with Visual Studio VC++ 2015 on Windows10, referring to: http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/win32.html.

Then, I got the following errors:

```
termination_test.c
.\tests\termination_test.c(82): error C2057: expected constant expression
.\tests\termination_test.c(82): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
.\tests\termination_test.c(82): error C2133: 'in': unknown size
.\tests\termination_test.c(83): error C2057: expected constant expression
.\tests\termination_test.c(83): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
.\tests\termination_test.c(83): error C2133: 'out': unknown size
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

"termination_test.c" is originally from:
http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/download.html 
and here is the function which causes the errors:

```
static void
simple_test (int converter)
{
    int ilen = 199030, olen = 1000, error ;

    {
        float in [ilen] ;
        float out [olen] ;
        double ratio = (1.0 * olen) / ilen ;
        SRC_DATA src_data =
        {   in, out,
            ilen, olen,
            0, 0, 0,
            ratio
        } ;

        error = src_simple (&src_data, converter, 1) ;
        if (error)
        {   printf ("\n\nLine %d : %s\n\n", __LINE__, src_strerror (error)) ;
            exit (1) ;
            } ;
    } ;

    return ;
} /* simple_test */
```

I simply modified these two lines to:

```
        float in [199030] ;
        float out [1000] ;
```

... then, worked perfectly.

However, what's wrong with the definition?

```
int ilen = 199030, olen = 1000, error ;
```

I put 'const' in front of int, then I got another error "C2166: l-value specifies const object".
How can I make it error-free?

(P.S., This is an open-source code, so there shouldn't be any errors. This isn't a question, but I just wonder why.)

Comment: In the error above, *expected constant expression* does ***NOT*** mean `const int x`. It means a constant expression whose value is known at compile time, like `#define ilen 199030` and `#define olen 1000` or `enum {olen = 1000, ilen = 199030 }'`

Comment: The code is correct. It is your compiler which is not. MSVC does not support 17 year old features of the C standard like VLAs. Use a modern standard compliant compiler like gcc or clang.

Comment: @David C. Rankin That's what I wanted. Now it works fine. I capitalized those two constants, to show that they are not changeable. Please make your comment an answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Olaf However, Microsoft Visual C++ is recommended by the author in [Mega-Nerd](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/win32.html). I had no choice.

Comment: @IanHacker Your question was what is wrong with the definition (of the arrays). I answered that question. Using enums is basically the same as using the integer constants, which is what you already discovered.

Comment: @2501 Yes, but I also asked how I could make it error-free.  David C. Rankin made it error-free. So, I would like to give him more points.

Comment: @IanHacker You yourself already did that, like this: `float in [199030]`, #define does exactly this, it is just more convenient.

Comment: @2501 Yes, you're right, I already did it, but without using 'ilen' and 'olen'. 'ratio' was still calculated based on 'ilen' and 'olen', so it looked very weird. That might be different from the author's intention. Using #define solved my concern.

Comment: That is nonsense! C++ is a different language and that is clearly C code (C++ for instance does not support VLAs). The answer of @2501 is correct, David is wrong here.

Comment: @2501: Actually _enum constants_ always have type `int` (that is one problem with them in certain contexts). Nevertheless are they the only symbolicv constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, the subtle point you were missing is that in C, array declaration requires a *constant* expression for the array size (e.g. `array[CONST]`). ***fn1.*** When you declare:

```
int ilen = 199030, olen = 1000, error ;
```

Neither `ilen` or `olen` are *constant expressions*. (the easy way to think about it is you could easily do `ilen = ilen + 2;` -- so `ilen` isn't a *constant expression*.)

Constant expressions are generally created by macro with `#define` or `enum` (which create global constants). (and you generally CAPITALIZE constants -- just to distinguish then from other variables). So you could do:

```
#define ILEN 199030
#defile OLEN 1000
```

or

```
enum { OLEN = 1000, ILEN = 199030 };
```

and then declare your `float` arrays:

```
float in [ILEN],
     out [OLEN];
```

***fn 1.*** Modern C compilers allow allow the use of the *variable length array* which can be declared in the way you have attempted, but as others have pointed out, your compiler does not support VLAs.

Comment: Solved by your answer. It was the quickest and most accurate answer. So I give you the point. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. There are other good answers too, maybe I'm just longer winded in my answer `:)`

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. C does support variable length array since C99 (they made it optional with C11, but any modern compiler supports them as it also supports C99.

Comment: I have to adjust my previous comment: The introduction is wrong. Minor flaw: `#define` does not create a constant, but a macro. C has no symbolic constants than _enum-constants_ (which are always `int`). The recommended way is indeed to use a macro to allow the compiler pick the correct type or specify the type in the macro. Enums in C are often near useless due to their restrictions.

Comment: Yes, there is a subtle distinction, added `macro` to differentiate the `#define` from the `enum`. (those are fairly skinny hairs for the purpose of the answer)

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio doesn't support variable length arrays.

The variables ilen and olen that defined the size of the array are not constant expressions (from here on described as: constants), so the following are variable length arrays:

```
float in [ilen] ;
float out [olen] ;
```

Values 199030 and 1000 are constants, so the following are just regular arrays:

```
float in [199030] ;
float out [1000] ;
```

Defining an object with a const qualifier will not make an object a constant.

You can use `#define` to define your values as macros, but this is identical to writing the constants manually, as the defined macros are replaced before compiling the code with the values they denote.

```
#define ILEN 1000
int array[ILEN];
```

is converted to:

```
int array[1000];
```

before before compiling begins.

Of course you should use `#define` as it is much more convenient and less error-prone.

Comment: I see your point. As Olaf suggested, if I used gcc or clang, I wouldn't have such errors. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid, you didn't mention #define in the first edition. That was what I really wanted. I already raised your answer, too. Thank you again for your explanation.

Answer (score -2):

The size of an array, at least in C89, must be a costant expression. A costant expression is an expression whose value doesn't change. Here's few examples of constant expressions:

```
#define SIZE (200)
...
int v[200];/* Ok*/
int w[200 + 1]; /*Ok because 200 + 1 does always 201*/
int y[SIZE]; /* Better*/
...
```

This implies that you cannot use a variabile to specify the array size, even if you declare it using "const" keyword because you fan change value of a const value by taking advantage of pointers.

```
int n = 10;
const int size = 10;
int v[n]; /* Wrong in C89 and non C99 fully compliant compilers!*/
int x[size]; /* Again, not valid because costant value != costant expression*/
```

To verify that const value can be changed,try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    const int a = 0;
    int *p = &a;
    printf("Now a is %d\n",a);
    *p = 1;
    printf("Now a is %d\n",a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


}
```

You'll see that a's value changes after the first call to printf. This behaviour is anyway compiler-dependant,in fact GCC allows you to change a const value but clang doesn't. That's why you can't use variables for the size of an array. C99 standards introduced VLAs (Variable Lenghts Arrays) and many other orrible features. With -std=c99 flag (or equivalent for non-GCC compatible compilers) you can use variables for specifying the size of an array, but this is a **bad** thing to do because it hides a call to malloc. C99 extensions were substantially introduced on favor of GCC and Numerical C and nowdays many compilers reject some features of C99 standards. Visual Studio compiler does not -rightly- support VLA,so you have two options:
- use malloc
- avoid dynamic memory (preferable)

In serious contexts malloc is not an option since it is strictly forbidden by strict standards such as MISRA/C and NASA subset. But even in "not so critical" environment avoiding the use of malloc is a good practice because it makes easier for you to write predictable and bug free code since you don't have to worry about memory leaks, forgotten free() etc. The solution consists in allocating a big pool of memory at the very beginning of the program and using it when needed.

To sum up the best way to declare an array is:

```
#define SIZE (...)
...
int v[SIZE];
...
```

Comment: Not my down-vote, but … Using a VLA does not hide a call to `malloc()`; the array is not dynamically allocated.  VLAs are not unconditionally bad; in fact, they are extremely useful.  If the sizes are not checked, then you can run into problems, but C provides you with lots of other ways of cutting your own throat and many people exploit many of them — with predictable results.  Just because the tool is dangerous doesn't mean it shouldn't exist; it means it should be used with due care.  And while there are places where `malloc()` et al are proscribed, that is not the generality of C code.

Comment: Invoking undefined behaviour does not prove anything. The part about `malloc` etc. is nonsense. In C++ you would also forbid using major parts of the standard librariy, `new`, etc.? The same in Python? VLAs are not more related to `malloc` than fixed-length arrays. Not using dynamic memory allocation in **embedded software** has other reasons, most notably predictability of run-time and memory allocation. Many such systems use e.g. pools, which actually share the issues you write with `malloc`&friends (they are very well allowed by e.g. MISRA).